# Get InkCanvas data for realtime drawing

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP, I've been reading Microsoft docs for day and couldn't find a way to get the stroke value to broadcast other `InkCanvas` on difference clients using SignalR core. do you guys know how to get the current `InkCanvas` value so I can broadcast it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to serialize and deserialize all strokes from an `InkCanvas` to and from a stream:

```
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(outputStream);
```

And

```
inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.LoadAsync(inputStream);
```

The [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/save-and-load-ink) contain a complete sample.

In case you don't want to keep "redrawing", which would not be efficient in this real-time scenario,, you could also serialize and send individual strokes one by one. `InkStroke` class has [`GetInkPoints` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstroke.getinkpoints#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStroke_GetInkPoints) which returns the list of points in the stroke. You can serialize those and on the connected clients recreate the strokes using [`InkStrokeBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokebuilder).